# Gnuplot - font from LaTeX

Tags: fonts, gnuplot

How to set the default font from LaTeX to gnuplot, please?

[image]

```
set encoding iso_8859_1
set term pngcairo size 1500,1000 enhanced font "???????,28"
set output "file.png"
```

**Edit after advice**
I downloaded cmunrm.ttf and use

```
set encoding iso_8859_1
set term pngcairo size 1500,1000 enhanced font "cmunrm,28"
```

However this has happened:

[image]

Comment: Have you installed the font? Have you restarted gnuplot?

Comment: I haven't installed it. Is it not sufficient to give it into the same folder. By the way, this font must be in the computer. LaTeX uses it - Computer Modern.

Comment: My guess would be that gnuplot is looking in the font folder of the operating system. By the way what is your operating system? So you have to install it on your system. And I would guess that LaTeX has its fonts stored somewhere else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use a special font you have to install it.
In my case this would be, e.g. `cmr10.ttf`.
You can find the cm fonts in the [ctan archive](https://ctan.org/tex-archive/fonts/cm/ps-type1/bakoma/).

**Code:**

```
set title "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ\nabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz" font "cmr10,20"

plot x
```

**Result:**

[image]